# Include PHP inside CSS file without PHP extension

Tags: php, ubuntu, apache2

I understand that I can name a file `main.css.php` and then set headers inside the file like so:

`<?php header("Content-type: text/css; charset: UTF-8"); ?>`

I can then dynamically set my styles and I have this working fine.

However, I would like to achieve the same effect with the name of the file simply being `main.css`, without exposing the PHP extension. How can I go about achieving this? The server is running Apache 2 on Ubuntu.

Current HTML: `<link href="main.css.php">`
Desired HTML: `<link href="main.css">` (still includes PHP)

Comment: generate the css and css file via php

Comment: A dirty hack you could use if placing in the PHP file in `main.css/index.php` and then linking to the file/folder as `main.css`.

Comment: @Chris Well yes, as I said in the question I'm already generating the css via php. My question asks how to generate the css without referencing a file with the `php` extension...

Comment: generate the file as well... Create a new css file, write your generated css to it...

Comment: @Chris Could you please explain further what you mean by generate the file?

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_file_create.asp

Comment: Thanks, that looks like it might work. Could you please submit it as an answer so I can select it? :)

Comment: @Chris That said, to generate the css file do you not have to access a php file that executes fopen first? Back to step one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is just for apache2 and php? Then one idea would be to interpret the `.css` as a `.php` which can be done by editing the `.conf` that includes the php extension or find this line somewhere in the config files:

```
AddType application/x-httpd-php .php
```

and edit to show

```
AddType application/x-httpd-php .php .css .phtml .etc .etc
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the mod_rewrite for it.
Create the .htaccess file in your css directory and put this code:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /your_css_dir/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php [L]
```